# How to connect node js and supabase in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, supabase-database

how to connect node js and supabase .I have completed front end using react . I need to get image as input from the user and store it in the DB.I need to fetch those images and display it in cards.

I have no idea as I am new to supabase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @supabase/supabase-js package to connect with supabase database.

```
npm install @supabase/supabase-js
```

dbConfig.ts

```js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
export const supabase = createClient('https://<project>.supabase.co', '<your-anon-key>')
```

For more details [refer supabase tutorial](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/nextjs).

Comment: I have completed these works. I need to get the image as input from user and store in supabase.How to do it?.

Comment: You can use supabase storage for storing any digital content https://supabase.com/storage

Comment: thanks bro i have connected

Comment: @MYTHREYANP I suggest you to click on [this mark](https://prnt.sc/k43QqJj73rLQ)

Answer (score -1):

you will write this in `index.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const databaseName = 'products';
const username = 'admin';
const password = '1234';
 
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv:// ${username}:${password} .net/${databaseName}`,

e=() =>{
if(e){console.log(e);}else{console.log("connected to database");}}
);
```

write this part in the terminal
If used this way, you don't need to download the MongoDB program to the device.

```
$ npm install mongoose
```

Comment: Im using supabase.